# Coursea.org? Comparable to actual college level credit?

Tags: cv, online-learning

I have the option of undertaking a Coursera.org course in *An Introduction to Interactive Programming in Python*, which is stated to be eligable for a *Fundamentals of Computing Specialization* , which they state is a *Verified Certificate*. This certificate costs 50$ though, and even though I can and probably will take the course free, **would this type of course be looked upon as something equivalent to a introductory comp. science course at the college level? Would it be resume worthy or am I just being "sold" something?**

I am not trying to badmouth the people at Coursera, I am sure they have noble intentions, but I am a skeptic at heart. Here is a link to the course in question.